# Is constant time cascade-computing possible?

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, data-structures

This is an educational-purpose question about limitation of computer technology.
I have a mindset that the below program is impossible to be created.

Let's say I have to develop an accumulating statistic datastructure.
Here is the specification :-

- User can `update(i,value)` to `data[i]` in `O(1)` (average case).
- User can query `getAccu(i)` = `data[0]+data[1]+...+data[i]` in `O(1)` (average case).
- I can't assume order of calling of the two functions in any way.

Here is my code ([coliru demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bd60ab60e83f479c)).
It doesn't meet the above requirement though :-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
int data[5]={0,1,2,3,4};
int accu[5]={0,1,3,6,10};
/** assume that index always >=1 */
void update(int index,int value){  //O(n) i.e. O(array length)
    data[index]=value;
    for(int n=index-1;n<5;n++){
        accu[n]=accu[n-1]+data[n];
    }
}
int getAccu(int index){            //O(1)
    return accu[index];
}
int main(){
    update(2,12);
    //note: data = 0,1,12,3,4
    //      accu = 0,1,13,16,20
    std::cout<<getAccu(3)<<std::endl; //16
    //update() ... getAccu()... update() ...
}
```

Without limitation about size of memory storage and type of datastructure,
is it possible to make both functions `update(index,value)` and `getAccu(index)` be `O(1)`?

If yes, how?  If no, why?

Sorry for the obscure topic.  I can't find a more suitable one.

Comment: This has got nothing to do with limitations of computing technology.   It is related to limitations of arbitrary requirements for constant-time updates of multiple connected variables.

Comment: @Peter  I imagine it might be possible, but our current researches are not up to that point.   Ex. In old days before Hash is invented, it is impossible to find a generic data structure with O(1) in almost every operation.  .... I think this is one of them.  .... If you still think I use incorrect words, feel free to edit it.  Thank. :)

Comment: Using some kind of tree, you may be able to do `log n` for both operations. Then, making the updates lazy, you can detect the case where there were many updates between 2 queries and handle it differently. Everything constant time seems optimistic.

Comment: @Marc Glisse   It sounds great .... it is quite too difficult for me .... may you elaborate more?  I am excited.

Comment: @cppBeginner - Your characterisation that hash tables give O(1) in "almost every operation" is false.   They give averaged and amortised case complexity, and O(n) worst case complexity.      You might think it is possible to meet your requirements, and you might even be right, but unless you provide evidence and other people can USE your result, your assertion is meaningless.

Comment: @Peter You are correct.  I forgot about the worst case. I will add the  "average case" word to the question.  Thank.

Comment: @cppBeginner For log n, the idea is to maintain a balanced binary search tree, which in addition stores in each node the total of the subtree rooted at that node. When you update one value, you only need to update the log n subtotals in a path from the root to that element. Computing the accumulator is just locating the right node from the root, and adding the left subtotal every time you go right.

Comment: @Marc Glisse  Genius! It can be extended to a dirty-flag tree.  If you post as a solution, I will upvote it.   Even though it is `log(n)`, it is still really useful in practice. Thank a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing everything in constant time seems optimistic. If you don't mind an `O(log n)` complexity, you could maintain a balanced binary tree that store in each node the total of the subtree rooted at that node.

When you update one value, you only need to update the log n subtotals in a path from the root to that element.

Computing the accumulator is just locating the right node from the root, and adding the left subtotal every time you go right.

Instead of doing the updates eagerly, you can add them in constant time to a list of to-be-updated items, then when you get a query and that list is not empty you can either do each update in `log n` or if there are many updates update only the values in `O(1)` and recompute the whole accumulator in `O(n)`, but that's only worth the trouble if you may get many updates between 2 queries.

Comment: It is a great answer, thank.   Where did you get the idea from? i.e. does this cool technique have a name?  I want to read more about it.

Comment: No idea, storing subtotals in a tree is a fairly standard technique but I don't have specific examples in mind.